# Dialog box does't get opened when clicked on p:commandLink in jsf primefaces?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, primefaces-dialog-framework

I am trying to open a dialog box in JSF using p:commandLink

```
<p:commandLink id="linkId" update="@this someDialogId" value="open dialog" action="#{someBean.someAction(id)}"/>

<p:dialog closable="true" id="someDialogId" closeOnEscape="true" maximizable="true" minimizable="true" fitViewport="true" modal="true" header="Task Details" rendered="#{someBean.displayDiag}" visible="#{someBean.displayDiag}" >

    // Something displayed
</p:dialog>
```

But nothing happens when I click over the p:commandLink ?

This **p:commandLink and p:dialog** are located in different div's inside the same form.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25339056/understanding-primefaces-process-update-and-jsf-fajax-execute-render-attributes

Comment: I read it and tried using p:ajax update="@this id" or f:ajax execute="Id" but none seem to work, what is happening is when I click link to to dialog box nothing happens and when some other item is clicked then dialog box enters.

Comment: @JasperdeVries My whole application is suffering from this refreshing issue, it will be great help if you can pin point how to stop refreshing whole form when dialog box opens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the PrimeFaces showcase: https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/overlay/dialog/basic.xhtml

You update the dialog but you do not open it.

First of all your dialog needs a widgetVar property. Let’s say it's "myDialog".

Then in your commandLink you add a java script handler for oncomplete. There you open the dialog.

Like `<p:commandLink ... oncomplete="PF('myDialog').show()" ... />`